# Show and Hide Fragments without Custom Animation

Tags: android, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I am having 3 fragments in my activity. I plan to hide 2 and show 1. Below is the code that works.

```
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator
            .fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out).show(fragment1)
                        .hide(fragment2).hide(fragment3).commit();
```

Since I don't want animation, I remove the `setCustomAnimations` from the chain as below.

```
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(fragment1)
                        .hide(fragment2).hide(fragment3).commit();
```

However, after removing this, the fragments are now no shown anymore i.e. Fragment1 is not shown as well. Do we really need `setCustomAnimations` to work?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your fragment classes are A,B,C. Try something like this:

```
void switchFragment(int fragmentId){
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction() 
.replace(R.id.placeHolder, getFragment(fragmentId))
.setCustomAnimations(...)
.commit();
}

Fragment getFragment(int id){
return id==1? A.newInstance() : id==2 ? 
B.newInstance() : C.newInstance();
}
```